# Autopopulating end date as (start date +30 days) using infopath

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, sharepoint-list, datepicker, auto-populate

I am trying to auto populate a field END DATE as (START DATE + 30 days) in an infopath form which should autopopulate end date in date format. Can anyone help me here. Thank you.

Comment: Google 3 things, defining variable in infopath, add date formula in infopath, and last auto populate fields in infopath. After that combine it into one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy using infopath rules. Add a rule for start date field. Set the condition to be start date is not blank. For actions, add action "set fields's value". Configure it to set the end date to be start date+30 days, just like the screenshot below. The field5 is your end date field. 
[image]

Comment: Thank you sooo much, Jerry. It helped me! :)